# How to check which html tag is the title field using in umbraco

Tags: jquery, controller, umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to check on backend which tag user is using for title field on any content page. e.g. `h1 or h2` in Umbraco

Comment: Can you give an example please? It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: If we have a field in umbraco content page named title, but we want to check what it is rendered as, whether <h1>Title here</h1> or something else in preview mode while in back office

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco doesn't have a specific template that is used for all sites built using Umbraco.  As such, its difficult to answer your question directly.  Here are some ways you could find out:

- In your browser, right-click and either "View Source" or "Inspect Element" and find the title that you are looking to get more information for.  If you add something unique (a * or some character) that may help you to find it.  The text of the title should have the h1 or h2 tags surrounding it.
- Alternatively, if you have access to the Settings section in the back-office, you could attempt to look at the template or partial view for the page in question.  To find the template for a content page, go to the Properties tab and look at the currently selected template.  In the template you will need to look for something that looks like Umbraco.Field("title") and see what tags are around it.  Searching for "title" may help as well.

Hope that helps